# Lost local file main.css after commit & push

Tags: python, css, django, github, pycharm

I've finished my project and was trying to commit and push changes. I trought it was successfully, but when I went to the site I saw that there are no styles.

Everything was committed successfully except main.css. It was replaced from last commit to my local pc and full-done css file was delated respectively

Commit and push were done by PyCharm. Pycharm Local History - Show History not available for main.css

I tried `git reflog`, here is the output:

```
PS D:\PyProjects\ElectricCarsStore> git reflog

9b2ccd3 (HEAD, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from c6f4aa2b2196603cd1af12e0e06ae9e6767b8b1a to 9b2ccd3

c6f4aa2 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from afcf0469d2369145e0296eac5b7e693a0508ba29 to c6f4aa2

afcf046 (master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master to afcf046

afcf046 (master) HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to afcf046

9b2ccd3 (HEAD, origin/master) HEAD@{4}: merge origin/master: Merge made by the 'ort' strategy.

c6f4aa2 HEAD@{5}: commit: Ready project v.1.0

afcf046 (master) HEAD@{6}: commit (initial): Initial commit
```

I will be grateful for your advice.